# How to remove all symlinks to a specified file with an android/busybox shell command?

Tags: android, linux, command

I want to remove all symbolic links to `/system/bin/toolbox` in the `/system/bin/` directory on my android phone, other symlinks should be kept.

i.e. Delete `cat -> toolbox` , `df -> toolbox`, etc. Keep `mount -> busybox`.

How can I write the command? (I have busybox installed already.)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you know how to use adb shell?

Comment: Yeah, I can type command in adb shell on my computer, or in the android terminal emulator on my phone. I just don't know which command can do this task. Maybe "find"? @btse

Answer (score 3):

Ahoy,

In a bash shell you will want to run the following command after reading this post:

```
#find / -type l -exec rm {} +
```

This Command will search through the root file system (change to the path of the search path) and locate symlinks (identified by the -type l).  Once it finds symlinks, it will use the --exec argument to run a command.  In this case the command is unlink, and the file path is replaced where {} appears in this command.  The command is ended with a plus sign.

This command is destructive and should only be run when you understand the command and it is your desired intent, however in it's current state may leave any Linux system this command is run on un-bootable since Linux often relies on symlinks.

EDIT: updated unlink to rm.  Looking at the code for rm and unlink, they make the same system call. However, rm accepts multiple arguments.

Comment: Thanks. I replaced `/` with `/system/bin`, but it seems that _unlink_ only accepts **one** parameter, so this does not work...  `find /system/bin -type l -exec unlink {} ;`, `find /system/bin -type l -exec rm {} +` and `find /system/bin -type l -delete` are both OK.

Comment: I'm looking for a command which can remove all symlinks to _toolbox_, e.g. `cat -> toolbox` and `df -> boolbox`. Other symlinks should be kept, e.g. `mount -> busybox`.

Comment: Finding symlinks pointed o a certain directory is going to be harder since there is no find option (that I know of) that searched based on the location a symlink points to.  You hope with this is to use -exec ls -l {}  and then use awk to parse out the link location and destination, then an awk script to see if the destnation matches.  if it does print out the link location and pipe that to xargs to unlink/delete.

Comment: Note that bash is not available on the device in question.

Comment: Seems much harder... My original goal is to replace `toolbox` with `busybox` and I've found a better solution with the environment variable $PATH. Thanks for your help:)@CitizenKepler

Comment: _mksh_ is built in to my phone's ROM, _ash_ and _hush_ is available from `busybox`. Of course bash is better! Maybe I should install one:)@ChrisStratton